# Xen not detecting xenbr0

Tags: centos, xen, xenserver

I am trying to create an HVM but when I start it up I see that it fails with this error message on the command line:

```
[root@xs5 xen]# xl create devoracle.cfg
Parsing config from devoracle.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route online [24897] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1462:domcreate_attach_vtpms: unable to add nic devices
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route offline [25012] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/block remove [24999] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/block failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/block remove [25002] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/block failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route remove [25132] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1219:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-route failed; error detected.
libxl: error: libxl.c:1583:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain 40
libxl: error: libxl.c:1542:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 40
libxl: error: libxl.c:1471:domain_destroy_cb: destruction of domain 40 failed
[root@xs5 xen]#
```

My configuration is currently set up for VIFS:

```
vif = [ "script=vif-route" ]
```

I have tried different combinations of this, such as adding the mac address for xenbr0 (and also xenbr1) and the device name, but it never gets picked up. Xenbr0 does exist, I can see it in ifconfig:

```
xenbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.x.x  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.x.x
        ether blah  txqueuelen 1  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 55823814  bytes 318634247570 (296.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 677426  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48675218  bytes 63768868848 (59.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

xenbr1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether foo  txqueuelen 1  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In addition, when I run the command, I see this occurring in the xen-hotplug.log:

```
xenstore-read: couldn't read path backend/vbd/40/768/node
xenstore-read: couldn't read path backend/vbd/40/832/node
```

And am seeing this in the log files generated when I run the create command:

```
qemu: ignoring not-understood drive `be:0x4f96ba:40:0x733540'
medium change watch on `be:0x4f96ba:40:0x733540' - unknown device, ignored
```

Am I missing something? Any recommendations or help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Commenting out the vifs line from the configuration allows the HVM to start, but if this is the case, this won't allow connectivity to the outside world. Any advise on this would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on **Debian 9 Stretch** with **Xen 4.9**

The problem was that under `/etc/xen/scripts/vif-route:` line 26 `ifconfig` used. For some reason, Debian replaced `ifconfig` with `ip address` so you need to install `net-tools` to get vif-route script working by:

```
apt install net-tool
```

Comment: Still not working here. Debian 9. Xen 4.9 net-tools installed machine restarted what i am still missing?